# update wordpress plugin table rows with php forms

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

This is my first time making a wordpress plugin. I'm trying to create a form with multiple rows, so each row in the sql table can be updated individually. With the script below i can only edit the last row and not the other ones.

### PHP Form

```
<form name="edit_from" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-content/plugins/menu/process.php" method="post">
<?php foreach($resultupdate as $key => $row ) { ?>
<tr id="product">
<td id="naam"><input name="id1"  value="<?php echo $row->ID ?>"/><input type="text" name="productnaam[<?php echo $row->ID ?>]" value="<?php echo $row->PRODUCT ?>" /></td>
<td id="prijs"><input type="text" name="price[<?php echo $row->ID ?>]" value="<?php echo $row->PRICE ?>" /></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="update" /></td>
<input name="id[<?php echo $row->ID ?>]"  type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row->ID ?>"/>
<input name="cat[<?php echo $row->ID ?>]" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row->CAT ?>"/>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</form>
```

### Process Part

```
if ($_POST['Submit'] == 'update') {
$product=$_POST['productnaam'];
$price=$_POST['price'];
$cat=$_POST['cat'];
$ID=$_POST['id'];

$update = "UPDATE " . $table_name ." SET PRODUCT = '" . $product ."', PRICE = '" .$price ."', CAT = '" . $cat ."' WHERE ID = '" . $ID . "'";
$results = $wpdb->query( $update );
}
```

What am i doing wrong? Thank a million for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to loop on every element of your array.
As the inputs from your Form are array (with [] like id[] or cat[] or price[])

I'd do this :

```
if ($_POST['Submit'] == 'update') {
        $products = $_POST['productnaam'];
        $prices = $_POST['price'];
        $cats = $_POST['cat'];
        $IDs = $_POST['id'];

        if (!empty($IDs) && is_array($IDs)) {
            foreach ($IDs as $id)  {
                //a little check of existing values
                $price = is_array($prices) && isset($prices[$id]) ? $prices[$id] : '';
                $product = is_array($products) && isset($products[$id]) ? $products[$id] : '';
                $cat = is_array($cats) && isset($cats[$id]) ? $cats[$id] : '';
                $update = "UPDATE " . $table_name . " SET PRODUCT = '" . $product . "', PRICE = '" . $price . "', CAT = '" . $cat . "' WHERE ID = '" . $id . "'";
                //here you have to check the return of the query
                $results = $wpdb->query($update);
            }
        }
    }
```

hope this help :)

Comment: I implemented the code, but for some reason the value in the table won't change.

Comment: Thank you. It worked with another modification included. By putting the <form> tag in foreach, I can edit a single table row.